# Can you set Fixed File Input column definitions dynamically in Pentaho data-integration (PDI)?

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I have a metadata file which contains the column name, starting position, and length. I would like to read these values and define my columns within a FIXED FILE INPUT step.

Is there a way to do this in PDI? My file contains over 200 columns at a fixed widths and manually entering the information would be very time consuming especially if this definition changes over time.

Comment: May you please provide the sample file which you are using for this functionality ???

Comment: I have found this question under data integration..let me kow what is pdi

Answer (score 0):

Use MetaData Injection Step to inject the MetaData into prescribed steps , refer [Matt Casters on figuring out delimited file](http://www.ibridge.be/?p=273) and [MetaData Injection description](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection)